# Shouldn't the Python client for BigQuery work with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, multiprocessing

As per the [Python BigQuery client documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html#example-usage), it seems that multiprocessing should work.
But I keep getting an error when trying a simple load to a BigQuery table from a pandas dataframe using multiprocessing and I wonder if the following statement from the doc would have anything to do with it.

> In multiprocessing scenarios, the best practice is to create client instances after `multiprocessing.Pool` or `multiprocessing.Process` invokes `os.fork()`.

I wrote my code based on this [GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table) (google-cloud-bigquery), that just tries to create 2 processes to load two different pandas dataframe on the same table (I have also tried to load them on two different tables and got the same error):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import random

def trying():
    #This is just to create random values to create the dataframe.
    values = np.round(np.random.uniform(0,1, (6,14)),2)* random.uniform(0,1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=list('abcdefghifklmn'))

    #I understand that I have to create the client for each process
    client = bigquery.Client()

    table_id = 'mydataset.new_table'
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
    job.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=trying)
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

This is the error I get and I can't figure out what is going on. Both processes throw the same error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test_multiproc_load.py", line 19, in trying
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1932, in load_table_from_dataframe
    parquet_compression=parquet_compression,
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 485, in dataframe_to_parquet
    arrow_table = dataframe_to_arrow(dataframe, bq_schema)
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 449, in dataframe_to_arrow
    bq_to_arrow_array(get_column_or_index(dataframe, bq_field.name), bq_field)
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 224, in bq_to_arrow_array
    return pyarrow.Array.from_pandas(series, type=arrow_type)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 755, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
    return array(obj, mask=mask, type=type, safe=safe, from_pandas=True,
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 269, in pyarrow.lib.array
    return _sequence_to_array(obj, mask, size, type, pool, c_from_pandas)
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 38, in pyarrow.lib._sequence_to_array
    check_status(ConvertPySequence(sequence, mask, options, &out))
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/.../snow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 127, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates
KeyError: 0
```

Is this a simple indexing error in my dataframe creation?
Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that your change fixed the issue? Basically there is no difference in both approaches.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And I don't understand why. That is the reason why I asked in my answer if anyone knows why. Because I agree with you that both approaches are the same. Did you have the chance to test it? You should get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is with `columns=list('abcdefghifklmn')`.
I am not sure why it doesn't work but if I specify like so `columns=['a', 'b',...]`, it works.
If anybody could explain why, it would be great.

Comment: `[...]` is called _a list literal_ while `list(...)` is actually a separate object, which has underlying cpython function calls (among other things happening). 

Using a _literal_, on the other hand, allows python to create bytecode directly, skipping the object setup of `list(...)` or `dict(...)`, for example. 

I'm not sure why this doesn't resolve (as you pointed out) but I'd assume bigquery has to do some low-level work in order to make multiprocessing shine w/Pandas.